# How to make view match parent dynamically

Tags: android, view

I have a layout as below. Location view maybe gone or visible and controlled by code. Thus the height of content view is variable based on the location view. But the divider view has always same height although it declared as matching to its parent.  Would you like to let me know how to make sure divider view has same height with its parent? Thanks a lot.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/divider"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/location"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/type"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />
      </LinearLayout>
      <View
        android:id="@+id/divider"
        android:layout_width="1px"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_divider_dashed_holo_dark" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Man you have it totally mixed up, why are you using linear layout inside? makes no sense. The relative layout has no orientation concept. About that height, possibly try alignTop and alignBottom to content, with wrap_content instead match_parent (also dont use fill_parent, atleast dont mix them with match_parent)

Answer (score 1):

Man you have it totally mixed up, why are you using linear layout inside? makes no sense. The relative layout has no orientation concept.

About that height, possibly try alignTop and alignBottom to content, with wrap_content instead match_parent (also dont use fill_parent, atleast dont mix them with match_parent).